# how to get selected tab on form submit in jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application Im using jquery UI tabs (jquery-ui-1.9.0) and setting a tab selected using the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: @Convert.ToInt32(Model.SearchModel.SearchType) })
});
```

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#articlesearchtab">Article</a></li>
   <li><a href="#othersearchtab">Other</a></li>
 </ul>

<div id="articlesearchtab">
   //content
</div>

<div id="othersearchtab">
   //content
</div>
```

User can go into either tab and update content. I need to get the content of selected tab on form submit. How can I get know the tab where user has selected?

Answer (score 0):

**[In jQuery UI 1.9, the  selected option is deprecated:](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-selected-option-renamed-to-active)**

> Deprecated selected option; renamed to active
>
> (#7135) The selected option has been renamed to active for consistency
>   with other plugins in jQuery UI. You should replace all uses of the
>   selected option with the active option.
>
> The selected option will be removed in 1.10.

**[Here is the new way to get the current tab:](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)**

> **Boolean:** Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.
>   **Integer:** The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.
>
> **Code examples:**
>
> Initialize the tabs with the active option specified:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
> ```
>
> Get or set the active option, after initialization:
>
> ```
> // getter
> var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
>
> // setter
> $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Call Same tabs in javascript using Code behind where you submit the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function OpenMoreDetails(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
</script>

protected void btnAttachDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //your code     
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "attach",  "OpenSearchOption('yourtabid',this);", true);
}
```

Comment: hi Learner, what happened ?you got solution